# Cloth "exploding" when texture change

Tags: cloth-simulation

So I'm trying to do a simple simulation where a have an object with a cloth flying over it and during that the object change texture. the problem i'm having is when the texture changes the cloth somewhat explode and fly straight up into the air. Is there anyway to fix this or should I just do a bake on another similar object without texture and then place the texture object after its baked?

Comment: Or will that even work?

Comment: How are you changing the texture? Did you bake the cloth simulation?

Comment: @RobertGützkow Im Changing the texture from a stone with displacement to a flat metal. I did a bake and the same thing happened. is it the change in displacement. because it worked before I pmlemented the change in texture.